# Getting highest primary key for specified column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is supposed to pull the highest primary key id for a specific request code:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   [QTRA410].[Admin].[qt_request] 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT Max(id) 
              FROM   [QTRAX4619410].[QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request]) 
       AND requestcode = 'FOREMAN';
```

Here is the current data in the table:

[image: screenshot1]

However the query is returning nothing at all and I don't understand why:

[image: screenshot2]

Strangely when I search for the request code 'JOB' it works fine:

[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: Why is it "strange"?, `id = 42` has a `RequestCode = 'JOB'`

Comment: As you can see from the table data above, FOREMAN should return 40 but it returns nothing. However JOB returns 42 as is expected.

Comment: Maybe 'FOREMAN' is actually 'FOREMAN ' (see the space).  Check the actual value in your [RequestCode] column perhaps.

Comment: @DavidTunnell that's because you are using `requestcode = 'FOREMAN'` outside of the subquery, you should use it inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might also try if [QTRAX4619410].[QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request] doeos not contain the requestcode:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   [QTRA410].[Admin].[qt_request] 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT Max(r1.id) 
              FROM   [QTRAX4619410].[QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request] r1
              join [QTRA410].[Admin].[qt_request]  r2 on r1.id = r2.id
       AND r2.requestcode = 'FOREMAN')
```

Comment: This is actually even more useful.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   [QTRA410].[Admin].[qt_request] 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT Max(id) 
              FROM   [QTRAX4619410].[QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request]
              WHERE requestcode = 'FOREMAN')
```

Comment: Yes this. the intial logic said teh max id had to be of the requestcode for FOrman and that is not the request code assocaited with the max id.

Answer (score 2):

Your two WHERE conditions are disqualifying id 40. The sub-SELECT for Max(id) returns 42 every time. Your requestcode condition requires that requestcode = "FOREMAN". There is no "FOREMAN" requestcode with an id of 42.

Answer (score 2):

Your subselect isn't being filtered by your request code.  I think you want something like

```
SELECT id 
FROM   [QTRA410].[Admin].[qt_request] 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT Max(id) 
              FROM   [QTRAX4619410].[QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request]
              AND requestcode = 'FOREMAN') 
       ;
```

or

```
SELECT id 
FROM   [QTRA410].[Admin].[qt_request] r
WHERE  id IN (SELECT Max(id) 
              FROM   [QTRAX4619410].[QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request] and requestcode = r.requestcode) 
       AND requestcode = 'FOREMAN';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it thusly:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT id
     , row_number() over (partition by reqeustcode order by id desc) as rn
  FROM   [QTRAX4619410].[QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request]
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
   and requestcode = 'FOREMAN'
```

Essentially, you're enumerating the rows in descending id order per requestcode and then picking the first (i.e. biggest). The optimizer can, well, optimize that but you wouldn't be wrong for thinking of it that way.